# Monitoring of traffic consumption on lunux python

Tags: python, linux, network-monitoring

**Goal:** control consumption of proxy.

I have a python code that connects to a third party API through a proxy.

**The difficulty** is that the script is multi-threaded (threads are launched through multiprocessing.Process), each thread has an ID. I need to understand how much each thread consumes traffic.

**I tried to save the PID** for each thread and catch traffic through linux nethogs, but the data is incorrect, part of packets are lost and the traffic does not converge with the real.

*Tell me, please, can there be a more concise solution for monitoring traffic consumption?*

Comment: *"threads are launched through multiprocessing.Process*" No, they aren't, that are processes.

Comment: @KlausD. sorry, what do you mean? Can you describe bit more?

Comment: This class does not create threads, it creates (sub-) processes, hence the name `Process`.